# :hover not working to show another image

Tags: html, css, hover

I have 2 images, initially i display the small image, but i move the big image out of the screen using CSS. But on hovering over the small image, i'm trying to bring the bigger image back onto the screen. But that doesn't seem to be working.

My Code:

```
<div class="info">

<div class="image">

<img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" id="image" />

<span><img src="<?php echo $popup; ?>"></span></div></div>
```

And CSS:

```
.info .image span {
position:absolute;
left: -9999px;
/*visibility: hidden;*/
/*display: none;*/
background-color:#eae9d4;
}

.info .image img:hover{
z-index: 50;
cursor:pointer;
}

.info .image img:hover span{
/*visibility: visible;*/
/*display: block;*/
top: -10px;
left: -20px;
/*z-index: 99;*/
}
```

What all i tried is in comments. Technically it should work. But i don't know where i'm going wrong.

Any Help is very much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<span>` is not a descendant of the image, it is a sibling.

You need to use the `+` combinator not .

Alternatively, you could work with `.image:hover` and not involve the `<img>` in the selector that includes `:hover` at all.

You will also need to adjust the positioning of the image. At the moment, all else being equal, you are positioning the top-left of the second image 10 pixels off the top of the window and 20 off the left hand side of it, so the top 10x20 pixels of the image will be out of sight.

Comment: Thanks a lot man!! Long day at work!! I totally ignored that!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just targeting the image ID

```
.image:hover {
z-index: 50;
cursor:pointer;
}
```